Python How to simulate cmd user input
I am using Windows 10.
I have a file (1.py) which contains getpass.getpass(), and I want to use python to enter the password automatically.
I tried subprocess.Popen(['py', '1.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE), but I can't write to it.
I included line breaks and cleared the buffer when writing to stdin.
What should I do?

what does getpass.getpass() do? does it have a input() method in it? can you give more details about it?

This is a python standard library function. You can find the code in your computer or open https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/getpass.py

Thank you. I wrote a working script but unfortunately, it works only in Linux systems, not Windows, sorry. If you intend to use Linux I can write my answer

What means you "can't write to it"? What happens? If there is an error message, show it completely as properly formatted text in the question.

If you want to programmatically write the password to 1.py, it seem impossible with builtin modules on Windows because getpass get the key press directly from the terminal, which seem different from stdin somehow. I guess a PTY is needed.

It seems you have to create a console or pseudoconsole to do this on Windows.

@MichaelButscher pseudoconsole works only in Linux, he uses windows 10.

@user70 Why should then Microsoft explain the pseudoconsole in its Windows documentation, including sample code with Windows API calls? :)

@MichaelButscher I'm sorry, I meant this won't work in Windows using Python -> import pty

@user70 Interesting. I wasn't even aware of this module (because I'm more used to Windows). Using the Windows pseudo console API will need ctypes or an external library.
